# Upgrading to the latest FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

I have a server running FreeBSD 11.0.

I have full backups, and would like to update to the lastest [11.1 release](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/11.1R/schedule.html).

How to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upgrade to FreeBSD 11.1, run as root:

```
freebsd-update upgrade -r 11.1-RELEASE
```

or

```
freebsd-update upgrade -r 11.1
```

The system may then show a few messages, concerning software installed, and ask

```
Does this look reasonable (y/n)?
```

To which you usually answer y.

The procedure than fetches the "metadata" and applies the necessary patches.

At the end, according to the instructions shown, you run manually, again as root:

```
/usr/sbin/freebsd-update install
```

and then you are normally shown the message:

```
Installing updates...
Kernel updates have been installed.  Please reboot and run
"/usr/sbin/freebsd-update install" again to finish installing updates.
```

You then reboot, and as soon you have the system up, you login, and run again as root:

```
#/usr/sbin/freebsd-update install
src component not installed, skipped
Installing updates... done.
```

Finally to check for the success of the operation:

```
$uname -r
11.1-RELEASE
```

After finishing the installation, you might want to run:

```
pkg update
pkg upgrade
```

To install the latest security updates.